# how to go to a particular date when we have the specific date

Tags: sql-server, netezza

Im trying to go to a particular date after finding a "start date"

Eg. I have the column start_date "01-OCT-2014" but now after getting the year "2014" from this data I want to create a column called "fin_yr" which should add +1 to the year and show the date "01-Jul-2015"

another eg:

start_date "23-APR-2013" then a new column called "fin_yr" should have the value "01-Jul-2014" 
thanks a ton (Netezza answers please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work in a Netezza environment, using the *extract* function ( *date_part* would have worked just as well) to add one to the year, and set the month and day to July 1st.

```
 SELECT start_date,
       to_date(extract(YEAR FROM start_date) +1 || '0701', 'YYYYMMDD') fin_year
    FROM (
          SELECT CURRENT_DATE start_date
       )
       foo;

 START_DATE |  FIN_YEAR
------------+------------
 2015-04-28 | 2016-07-01
(1 row)
```

Comment: yeah I tried something like this. Works well thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you column name is "dt" then you can add 1 year by doing this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, dt)
FROM foo
```

I don't understand how you go from 23-APR-2013 to 01-Jul-2014 though.  That's adding 1 year + some number of days.  If for example you want to add 1 year + 99 days you could do something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 99, DATEADD(year, 1, dt))
FROM foo
```